# How to install JDK sources?

Tags: jdk, openjdk, source-code

How can I download the source code of Java on my local machine, so I can reference it in an IDE?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Example for Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

**apt-get** puts it under the relevant JDK location as src.zip: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip`

Intellij IDEA recognized it automatically and started showing me the source code.

Answer (score 39):

In case of java 11 (on Ubuntu 18.04) I did:

First I install jdk 11:

`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`

I install the sources like this:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-source`

And I found them in `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip`

I use Eclipse so I go inside Eclipse's menu `Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs` 
and inside select
`java-11-openjdk-amd64 -> edit -> select the jar (jrt-fs.jar) -> Source Attachment -> External location -> /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip`

Now I happily read the java documentation! :)

Best of luck to all!

Comment: Where is the jrt-fs.jar? Is it inside the .zip?

Comment: No `jrt-fs.jar` should be in the `lib` directory of your JDK. For example `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jrt-fs.jar` Please check if you have it after you install `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` In Eclipse menu you can see it after you press `edit` button on the selected `JDK` and you can see it in `JRE system libraries` section.

Answer (score 0):

In case of java 13 simply run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-13-source`